# How can I pipe a command output to a CSV file in shell?

Tags: python, shell, scripting

~]$ date;daemon -ip  statistics data  | grep bytes

```
Fri Jun 22 13:58:37 +08 2018
1958391001 transmit bytes
1825330799 receive bytes
```

I want to Pipe these value to a CSV file as mentioned below.How can I do it?

|Date| Tx bytes|Rx Bytes|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this with `awk`:

```
daemon -ip statistics data | awk -v d="$(date)" '/transmit bytes/{t=$1} /receive bytes/{print "|" d "|" t "|" $1 "|"}'
```

**Output**

```
|Fri 22 Jun 2018 08:29:45 BST|1958391001|1825330799|
```

---

Or, if you prefer `printf`-style formatting:

```
daemon -ip statistics data | awk -v d="$(date)" '/transmit bytes/{t=$1} /receive bytes/{printf("|%s|%d|%d|\n",d,t,$1)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pipe the output of your command to `tr` in order to replace newlines by your separator, i.e.

```
....|tr '\n' '|'
```

you nearly have your whole string already complete, except for the leading `|`. So, if you store this string to a variable, i.e.

```
v=$(.....|tr '\n' '|')
```

you can append it to your csv file with

```
echo "|$v" >>your_file.csv
```